# Ejecutar un Runnable varias veces

Tags: java, android

Estoy usando el reproductor de video de https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView 
donde tengo un problema en la siguiente clase 
https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView/blob/master/fullscreenvideoview/src/main/java/com/github/rtoshiro/view/video/FullscreenVideoLayout.java

Con el siguiente metodo:

```
protected Runnable updateTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updateCounter();

        TIME_THREAD.postDelayed(this, 200);
    }
};
```

Configure media player con el metodo setLooping para que se reinicie el video al finalizar. mi problema es que al reiniciarse el video solo se ejecuta una sola vez el metodo updateCounter que se esta llamando desde el metodo run. como pueden ver el metodo updateCounter es el que actualiza los segundos del video. al momento de reiniciar el video se queda solo en el segundo 1. y de ahi no pasa. Cabe destacar que al reiniciar el video lo estoy reiniciando el segundo 2 con seekTo();.

Comment: Sería mucho más fácil ayudarte si pusieras también la parte del código en la que usas este método.

Answer (score 1):

El metodo  `updateCounter()`; es el que actualiza el contador, dentro de este metodo la variable a actualizar para reiniciar el contador y el Seekbar es :

```
 int elapsed = getCurrentPosition();
```

Para forzar a iniciar desde 0 la posicion de playback puedes realizarlo con `seekTo(0)`.

Veo que tu [clase](https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView/blob/master/fullscreenvideoview/src/main/java/com/github/rtoshiro/view/video/FullscreenVideoView.java) implementa `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener` por lo tanto dentro del método `onPrepared()` podrías reiniciar el contador:

```
@Override
synchronized public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    seekTo(0);
    videoIsReady = true;
    tryToPrepare();
}
```